# ¿Cómo puedo hacer consultas filtrandolas con minutos?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Tengo ese dilema o problema que no encuentro la manera de como realizar la consulta , quiero filtrar contenidos dinamicos  cada 20 minutos o 30 con django, he investigado pero no se si con timedelta se puede realizar

> Es decir quiero traer objetos o consulta cada 30 minutos, ¿hay alguna forma de realizarlo en django ?

Comment: Quizás te sirva programar una tarea periódica de Django a través de Celery. En Python existe el módulo threading que al importarlo, permite realizar una función cada una x cantidad de tiempo, por ejemplo: `import threading def probando(): threading.Timer(3.0, probando).start() print("Se ejecuta cada cada 3 segundos") probando() `, pero creo que lo que se ajusta más a tu planteamiento es utilizar Celery.

Comment: Puedes agregar una cache de 30 minutos. Despues que pasen esos 30 minutos se harán nuevas consultas.

Comment: Me puedes decir un ejemplo de como puedo realizarlo por ejemplo tengo mi query de esta manera : Post = post.objects.all() como puedo filtrarlo de la manera que dices ?